# MySQL ON Duplicate update not working

Tags: mysql

I am running the following Insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO list_subscribers (subscriberid, listid, emailaddress, domainname, format, confirmed, confirmcode, requestdate, requestip, confirmdate, confirmip, subscribedate, unsubscribed, unsubscribeconfirmed) 
VALUES ('203404', 1, 'blah@gmail.com', '@gmail.com', 'h', 1, '1234', 1282196458, '', 1282196458, '', 1282196458, 0, 0 ) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE emailaddress='blah@gmail.com', domainname = '@gmail.com', unsubscribed = 0, unsubscribeconfirmed = 0
```

And I am getting the following error back:

```
Error Code: 1062. Duplicate entry 'blah@gmail.com-1' for key 'subscribers_email_list_idx'
```

Here is what my table looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE `list_subscribers` (
    `subscriberid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `listid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `emailaddress` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
    `domainname` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
    `format` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
    `confirmed` char(1) DEFAULT '0',
    `confirmcode` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
    `requestdate` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
    `requestip` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
    `confirmdate` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
    `confirmip` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
    `subscribedate` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
    `bounced` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
    `unsubscribed` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
    `unsubscribeconfirmed` char(1) DEFAULT '0',
    `formid` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`subscriberid`),
    UNIQUE KEY `subscribers_email_list_idx` (`emailaddress`,`listid`),
    KEY `list_subscribers_sub_list_idx` (`subscriberid`,`listid`),
    KEY `subscribe_date_idx` (`subscribedate`),
    KEY `list_subscribers_listid_idx` (`listid`),
    KEY `confirmed_idx` (`confirmed`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4687107 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

I thought that this was exactly what the "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE" statement was for?  Why is it aborting the query because of a duplicate index?

Comment: Why do you provide a value for the auto-incrementing id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, looks like the duplicate issue was actually with the update.  Since there was a unique key defined for emailaddress,listid, when it was trying to do the update there was actually another entry that had a different subscriber id, but had the same emailaddress and listid.

This makes more sense to me since it was the Update statement that was actually producing the duplicate error, not just the insert statement.